# $\alpha(t_0)$ orthogonal to $\alpha^\prime (t_0)$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

Somebody asked this question a while back but only hints were posted--I want to have my entire proof examined.

> Let $\alpha(t)$ be a parametrized curve which does not pass through the origin. If $\alpha(t_0)$ is the point of $\mathrm{Tr}(\alpha)$ closest to the origin and $\alpha^\prime(t_0)\neq 0$, show that the position vector $\alpha(t_0)$ is orthogonal to $\alpha^\prime (t_0)$.

$\alpha(t_0)$ is closest to the origin, so:

$$|\alpha(t_0)|<|\alpha(t)|$$
for all $t\in I\setminus \{t_0\}$ where $I$ is the domain for the map $\alpha$. It follows that
$$|\alpha(t_0)|^2=|\alpha(t_0)||\alpha(t_0)|<|\alpha(t_0)||\alpha(t)|<|\alpha(t)||\alpha(t)|=|\alpha(t)|^2$$
for all $t\in I\setminus\{t_0\}$. Applying the definition of inner product to the inequality $|\alpha(t_0)|^2<|\alpha(t)|^2$, we obtain:
$$\alpha(t_0)\cdot\alpha(t_0)<\alpha(t)\cdot\alpha(t)$$
for all $t\in I\setminus\{t_0\}$. This strict inequality implies that the function
$$f(t)=\alpha(t)\cdot \alpha(t),\;\;\;t\in I$$
is minimized at $f(t_0)$. Hence, $f^\prime(t_0)=0$ and
$$\frac{d}{dt}[\alpha(t_0)\cdot\alpha(t_0)]=\alpha^\prime(t_0)\cdot\alpha(t_0)+\alpha(t_0)\cdot \alpha^\prime(t_0)=2\alpha^\prime(t_0)\cdot\alpha(t_0)=0$$
giving the desired result $\alpha^\prime(t_0)\cdot\alpha(t_0)=0$.

Does this seem valid? I am especially concerned about the line: "This strict inequality implies that the function $(\cdots)$ is minimized at $f(t_0)$ $\implies f^\prime(t_0)=0$". I appreciate any input. Thanks.

Comment: Your proof seems ok to me, the problem statement implies that $\alpha$ is differentiable at $t_0$ and so $f$ is as well.